# Whether $Hom_{D(A)}(P,X) \cong Hom_{K(A)}(P,X)$ hold?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $A$ be an algebra over a commutative ring $k$. We denote by $K(A)$ the homotopy category of complexes of $A$-modules and by $D(A)$ the derived category of $A$-modules.

Let $P$ be a projective $A$-module. Then $P$ can also be seen as a complex concentrated in degree $0$. Then is $Hom_{D(A)}(P,X) \cong Hom_{K(A)}(P,X)$ for any complex $X$ of $A$-modules? (I know that the morphisms from $P$ to $X$ in $D(A)$ are of the form $P \stackrel{\mu}{\longleftarrow} Z \stackrel{\nu}{\longrightarrow} X$, where $\mu$ is a quasi-isomorphism and $\nu$ is a morphism of complexes. So for any morphism from $Hom_{K(A)}(P,X)$, we can get a morphism in $Hom_{D(A)}(P,X)$. I don't know what to do next, thank you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the natural morphism $\text{Hom}_{\text K(A)}(P,X)\to\text{Hom}_{\text D(A)}(P,X)$ is an isomorphism.

By the dual of Theorem 14.1.5 p. 348 of **Categories and Sheaves** by Kashiwara and Schapira, it suffices to prove 
$$
\text{Hom}_{\text K(A)}(P,X)\simeq0\tag1
$$ 
whenever $X$ is exact.

Clearly $(1)$ holds when $P=A$, and thus when $P$ is free.

Moreover, if $(1)$ holds for $P\oplus Q$, then it holds for $P$ and $Q$.

This implies that $(1)$ holds for all projective modules.